# Suggestions for Firebase Firestore Data Structure

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've done a lot of reading lately through the documentation but have only just begun using Firebase and could use some suggestions on setting up the data structure for my first web app leveraging Firestore.

I've seen many examples online of code samples, but am having a hard time finding examples of data structures that are similar to what I'm looking to do.

The first project I'm working on (for fun, not commercial use) is to keep track of available conference rooms across multiple offices.

I was thinking of setting it up something like this;

```
Office Location A
  Room 1
    Available: Yes/No
    Employee: ____
    ReservedAt: ____
  Room 2
    Available: Yes/No
    Employee: ____
    ReservedAt: ____
  Room 3
    Available: Yes/No
    Employee: ____
    ReservedAt: ____
Office Location B
  Room 1
    Available: Yes/No
    Employee: ____
    ReservedAt: ____
  Room 2
    Available: Yes/No
    Employee: ____
    ReservedAt: ____
```

I come from the world of SQL and PHP, no noSQL databases are very new to me and I'm trying to think outside the usual box of how I would set up a SQL database.

Any input or feedback appreciated.

Comment: There is no single "correct data structure" in NoSQL land. All data is modeled to allow the use-cases that your app requires. This means that what works for one app, may be insufficient for another app. I'd recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), and then trying to implement the first basic use-cases of your app. If you get stuck, post back with the concrete use-case, data structure, and code you are struggling with.

Comment: Thank you for the recommended reading, that was very helpful!